# NestJs can't resolve service dependencies on a circular dependency

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, circular-dependency

i have the problem that i have a circular dependency in my project. Unfortunately I cannot solve this with forwardRef.

The following structure:

**OrderModule**

- *OrderService*

  - *I have the following dependencies in the orderService*
  - PriceService
  - CustomerService
  - SalePriceService
  - ...

**PriceModule**

- *PriceService*

  - *I have the following dependencies in the priceService*
  - OrderService
  - ProductService
  - ...

I've tried all the options from the Official Documentation.
[docs NestJs circular-dependency](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

What has to be considered here if there are more dependencies in a service?

Many thanks. Best regards.

**Update:**

order.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CustomerModule,
    ProductModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Order', schema: OrderSchema }]),
    forwardRef(() => PriceModule),
  ],
  controllers: [OrderController],
  providers: [OrderService],
  exports: [OrderService],
})
export class OrderModule {}
```

order.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService extends GenericCrudService<OrderDocument> {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Order.name) readonly order: Model<OrderDocument>,
    private readonly productService: ProductService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => PriceService))
    private readonly priceService: PriceService,
  ) {
    super(order);
  }
}
```

price.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CustomerModule,
    SalePriceModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Price', schema: PriceSchema }]),
    forwardRef(() => OrderModule),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [PriceService],
  exports: [PriceService],
})
export class PriceModule {}
```

price.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class PriceService extends GenericCrudService<PriceDocument> {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Price.name) readonly price: Model<PriceDocument>,
    private readonly customerService: CustomerService,
    private readonly salePriceService: SalePriceService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => OrderService))
    private readonly orderService: OrderService,
  ) {
    super(price);
  }
}
```

product.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PriceModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Product', schema: ProductSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [ProductController],
  providers: [ProductService],
  exports: [ProductService],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

product.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService extends GenericCrudService<ProductDocument> {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Product.name) readonly product: Model<ProductDocument>,
  ) {
    super(product);
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
The module at index [1] of the OrderModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule -> ProductModule -> PriceModule]
Error: Nest cannot create the OrderModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the OrderModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule -> ProductModule -> PriceModule]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why using `forwardRef` does not fix the issue?

Comment: Showing your code here, modules and services, would be very helpful in knowing what's happening

Comment: Hi @JayMcDoniel I've just added a updated the question with the code snippets and the error I'm getting.

Comment: Can you add the `ProductModule`?

Comment: Hi @JayMcDoniel, I've just added a updated the question and add the product module and product service, best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there's the obvious circular dependency that you have here: `OrdersModule` to `PricesModule` and back, that one is properly `forwardRef`fed. However, there's another, not so obvious circular dependency too. `OrdersModule` to `ProductsModule` to `PricesModule` because the next import would be `OrdersModule`. Because of this, `OrdersModule` needs to `forwardRef` the `ProductsModule` and `ProductsModule` needs to `forwardRef` the `PricesModule`. It looks like the services themselves aren't circular, so it's just the modules that need the forward ref. Always make sure to check the entire import chain, especially when Nest is trying to report something like it did with `Scope [AppModule -> ProductModule -> PriceModule]`.

Comment: Hello @JayMcDoniel, I understand that works perfectly. Thanks for the quick help :)